# Not able to login in VNCViewer

Tags: linux, unix, vnc, vnc-viewer

1. I created new user in Linux VM from root user with Putty.
2. And closed Putty session.
3. I login with my new user.
4. I run command

vncserver -geometry 1800x900

it gave some session id like :

```
host_name:session_id
```

with that : , i am trying to login in VNC, but

I am getting error "connect:connection refused"

**please give me your valuable suggestions**

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting an authorization error, but a connection error. You need to check if `iptables(8)` is active in the GNU/Linux side, and check if it's allowing connections to the VNC ports, usually 5800/tcp and 5900/tcp.
You can also try to `telnet(1)` that port from the client side.